# Do tamed oviraptors promote pooping?

Tags: ark-survival-evolved

I have an [oviraptor](http://ark.gamepedia.com/Oviraptor) at my base generating increased egg production from my other dinos. I swear poop production has skyrocketed as well though: my compost bins are always maxed out, and sitting amidst the ~50 nearby dinos can sometimes sound like a symphony of poo (constant fart sounds). This is especially noticable with my Phliomas, which are now pooping in burst fire mode, defecating 2 or 3 times before the first poo ball decomposes, creating an unsightly pile/stack behind them.

Until we get dung beetles on console, a lot of the dino waste is going to go to waste. I'm also curious if this is increasing the dino food consumption rate. Has anyone else experienced a fecal spike after taming an oviraptor?

Comment: Another one 'hilarious-if-not-gaming-related' questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may have been added to the linked page after this question was asked, but the wiki page for the oviraptor linked to in the question does state that it increases feces production, the very beginning of the "Utility" section:

"nce tamed, setting the Oviraptor on wander will increase the production speed of eggs in nearby tamed creatures (including mammals), indicated by an egg icon above all affected animals. **This effect will also increase the feces laying rate on all dinos nearby.**"

Comment: That definitely did **not** exist at time of posting, and for your efforts in coming back here to update, you sir get a green checkmark!

Answer (score 5):

As far as I know, every time a female dino defecates there is a 2% chance to also drop an egg, so with that logic in mind, I suppose it is not out of the realm of possibility that it also increases the amount of defecation.